# The volume "boot" has only 0 bytes s

Tags: boot

when I start up my computer I get the message "the volume "boot" has only 0 bytes disk space".  When I go into my boot file I have files in there that are empty.  I have opened them with firefox and office and both are empty.  Is it safe to delete those files?  There are vmlinuz. files and initred.img and system.map file names.

Answer (score 0):

Those may be crucially essential files. Instead, you should run:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Comment: where do I run those programs.  I do not know my way around a computer all that well.

Comment: anywhere in terminal